# Where to add wp_redirect on frontend pages?

Tags: redirect, front-end, wp-redirect

My main problem, that I generate forms based on data coming from the `init` hook. I cannot do it earlier because I use `get_current_user_id` to check which posts belong to the current user and the form data is based on a post. It is something like post edit forms. I struggle with the redirection, because form data is processed when I add a form to a page with the same form id that is sent with the form data. So I make sure this way that the actual form data is processed by the proper form. This matters a lot, because of proper sanitization and validation. Normally this should happen by running the plugin, but because the form is generated in the `init` hook, I have to do it too late to redirect. At least when I do `add_action('init', 'my_redirect')`, nothing happens. Is there a solution?

Comment: I got a solution with `add_action('template_redirect', $cb)`, but I am still not sure why `add_action('init', $cb)` did not work.

Comment: It's hard to say why your `init` solution wouldn't work without seeing the code you were working with. If you still need that answered, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/424313/edit) to include the code you were having trouble with.

Comment: @PatJ I edited the question.

Comment: @PatJ I am not sure why it did not work. I tried it again and now it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that currently this is the only reliable solution:

```
        if (is_admin()){
            header('Location: '. get_permalink());
            exit();
        }
        else
            add_action('template_redirect', function (){
                wp_redirect(get_permalink());
                exit();
            });
```

In the case of backend pages the `template_redirect` does not seem to be supported. If I use `wp_redirect` the redirection does not happen (maybe it is a bug) or the function is not defined yet.

Another alternative solution which works by both the frontend and backend pages is

```
        add_action('init', function (){
            header('Location: '. get_permalink());
            exit();
        }, 999);
```

If I add it with normal priority, it does not run, so better to add it with higher priority than the original `init` where we add it from. This makes sense, because the number isn't really the priority, but the running order of the callbacks. So when I add something from a 10 priority callback (which is the default), then it won't run if its priority is less than 10 or equals to 10.

Yet another solution is

```
        add_action(is_admin()?'init':'template_redirect', function (){
            header('Location: '. get_permalink());
            exit();
        }, 999);
```

I like this the best so far, because `template_redirect` certainly runs later in the case of frontend pages than `init` and it works in the case of admin pages as well.